# How to have SceneKit refresh at 120 Hz on iPhone 13 Pro?

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit

I have an app with an `SCNView` inside of it.

Without any modifications, when I first ran it on an iPhone 13 Pro, it ran at 60 Hz according to the frame rate shown when I set `showsStatistics = true`.

Investigating, I discovered both the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property of `SCNView`, and the `CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone` Info.plist boolean property.

However, setting the preferred FPS to 120, and setting `CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone` to `YES`, doesn't seem to affect the reported frame rate (although setting it to 30 for example does make it refresh at 30). I've also tried just setting the preferred frame rate and just setting the Info.plist property, but no combination of these have any effect either. [The official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/optimizing_promotion_refresh_rates_for_iphone_13_pro_and_ipad_pro) doesn't mention anything about SceneKit.

What am I missing to achieve the higher frame rate?

Comment: Did you set `CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone` to `<true/>` in your `Info.plist` file?  (Your question is slightly confusing as you mention setting it to `YES` which isn't valid for a plist file or swift).

Comment: Yes, it's `<true/>` when viewing the XML directly.

Comment: Ah I see; you set it within Xcode.  And you have `sceneView.isPlaying = true` and you've implemented the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate.renderer(_:updateAtTime:)` method?

Comment: I don't normally have `isPlaying = true` as the scene doesn't always need to update, but setting this property didn't fix it anyway. I do implement the delegate method.